# How should I append data in single object of s3 using multipart upload?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a task in which i want to upload some data in a single object of s3 continuously. I have created a lambda function in which I have called **initiated upload**, **upload part** (twice), and **completeMultipartUpload**. So when I test this lambda I get data in destination object as expected i.e.data from all source files without overwriting. But when I test lambda for second time the data gets overwrite whereas I want this data to get append at the end of destination object. How could I do this? Any idea?

Comment: Try it by enabling versioning feature of S3 bucket, So whenever you upload data it creates a version of the file without overwriting.

Comment: By using versioning, will I get data from  previous version of object in the new version? As later I want to run s3 select on complete object.

Comment: No, but your previous file/data will be saved from overwriting.

Comment: okk... this doesn't seem to help in my case... but thanks for your response...

Answer (score 1):

You can't really append data to an s3 object, it's all or nothing really - you can read the object back, add the new data to the object, and then re-save it to S3 in order to simulate the append  - but that would get slow if you are adding data often to large objects.

Comment: Any other workarounds possible? As I have very large files so reading files and appending will not work. And want to query using s3 select on full object.

Comment: A database might be the right choice if this is your requirement - DynamoDB for example, or a more traditional SQL.